# Proper shutdown of Akka actor system in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, akka

I'm using Akka in one of my web applications. The application is a standard Spring app that gets initialized in the Tomcat servlet container.

I have a simple ServletContextListener like this:

```
public class AkkaInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

      @Override
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
           ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("system");
           // initialize main top-level master actor here ...


      }

}
```

The contextInitialized gets called by Tomcat on the application's start up.
Now the question is, let's say I have a top level actor who may be escalated a failure from one of his children. I want this master actor to essentially log the failure that happened and shutdown the JVM afterwards. How can this be accomplished in a clean way?

Answer (score 6):

The clean way of shutting down an Akka application may be:

1) Stop getting incoming request from the outside world (depends on your implementation);

2) Send `PoisonPill`-s to all your top-level actors in the correct order (exact or similar to your main data flow in your app; also your routers should be able to broadcast `PoisonPill`-s to their routees);

3) Use the [Reaper pattern](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) to watch your actors and decide that all of them have processed all their messages and stopped and after that stop the ActorSystem (don't forget a reasonably high timeout for actors stopping to stop the ActorSystem in any case);

4) Await for the ActorSystem termination (`ActorSystem.awaitTermination(scala.concurrent.duration.Duration timeout)`);

5) Shutdown all other parts of your app which should be properly terminated;

6) Shutdown the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would it be wrong to call getContext().system().shutdown() in my postStop hook for the master actor? And then, wherever I've initialized my actor system, I can call actorSystem.registerOnTermination( { system.exit(1); } );

Comment: If your data flow is simple and there will be no possible further important data processing (by other actors) after stop of your master actor - then, I think, yes.