# Could not load [akka.event.Logging$Error$]

Tags: java, tomcat, akka

We have a service that implements the AKKA framework and runs as a Tomcat application.  When it is deployed into one of our test environments it is throwing an exception that is forcing that application to stop (see exception below).  I can get it to get by the exception after I bounce Tomcat a few times.    It is not deterministic and seems to involve a time lag.  It looks like something is causing a resource conflict, but I have yet to identify the culprit.  Has anyone come across this and how did you deal with it?

Exception text:
24-Aug-2015 16:56:15.000 INFO [TestCoordinatorSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-20] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [akka.event.Logging$Error$]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. **Could not load [akka.event.Logging$Error$]**. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1196)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
                at akka.event.BusLogging.notifyError(Logging.scala:1138)
                at akka.event.LoggingAdapter$class.error(Logging.scala:877)
                at akka.event.BusLogging.error(Logging.scala:1128)
                at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anon$2.uncaughtException(ActorSystem.scala:510)
                at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:398)
                at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
                at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
                at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
                at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Answer (score 0):

It seems harmless to me: a race between someone killing the application instance and the result of some asynchronous computation being available after that (the result actually seems an error - maybe a timeout)

If you want to get rid of this message you may try to shut down Akka [in some better way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806790/315306)